# vue double iterate in v-for

Tags: vue.js, leaflet, geojson

Hope you're all well.

I'm trying to display polylines on my vue2-leaflet map. Current problem at the moment is that I have to kind of iterate it double... to get the vertexlist? Please check below code and my comments!

example data format:
[0: {
linkid: "1220000102" 
fnode: "1220013900" 
flat: "37.4760079" 
flng: "127.0587882" 
tnode: "1220000100" 
tlat: "37.4715107" 
tlng: "127.0510469"  
vertexlist: Array(4) 
0: (2) ["37.4760532", "127.0587510", **ob**: Observer] 
1: (2) ["37.4743382", "127.0554621", **ob**: Observer] 
2: (2) ["37.4739651", "127.0547651", **ob**: Observer] 
3: (2) ["37.4715528", "127.0510043", **ob**: Observer] 
length: 4}]

I've got them in let linkList, and added it here:

```
 <l-feature-group>
  <l-polyline
    v-for="link in this.linkList"
    :key="link.linkid"
    :lat-lngs="polyline.link"
    :color="'green'"
  >
  </l-polyline>
</l-feature-group>
```

The thing is that, that :lat-lngs="" format is [[fromLat, fromLng], [vertexLat, vertexLnt], ... ,[vertexLat, vertexLnt], [toLat, toLng]] part.

I need to iterate vertex to get the all vertex data and display the correct polyline.

Any idea??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a computed property to prepare the data for leaflet:

```
computed : {
  links () {
    return this.linkList.map(l => {
       l.latlng = [[l.flat,l.flng], ...l.vertexlist , [l.tlat,l.tlng]]
       return l
    }) 
  }
}
```

```
<l-feature-group>
  <l-polyline
    v-for="link in this.links"
    :key="link.linkid"
    :lat-lngs="link.latlngs"
    :color="'green'"
  >
  </l-polyline>
</l-feature-group>
```

Or in the template:

```
<l-polyline
    v-for="l in this.linkList"
    :key="l.linkid"
    :lat-lngs="[[l.flat,l.flng], ...l.vertexlist , [l.tlat,l.tlng]]"
    :color="'green'"
  >
```